# AWS Cognito Sync fails after identity change

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-cognito

I'm struggling integrating AWS Cognito Sync into a Xamarin app. Everything works fine for both unauthenticated and authenticated cases as long as the authentication status doesn't change. If the user signs out and in again, CognitoSync doesn't recover after the sign-in. Things are fine again once the user restarts the app, but that can hardly be the solution...

I unfortunately couldn't find much information about what needs to be done on the CognitoSync side after a credential change. CognitoAwsCredentials extends from RefreshingAWSCredentials and as far as I understand I should only need to update that instance and clear its cache.

At sign-in:

```
CognitoAwsCredentials.AddLogin(providerName, idToken);
CognitoAwsCredentials.ClearCredentials(); // Clear cached credentials
```

At sign-out:

```
foreach (var provider in CognitoAwsCredentials.CurrentLoginProviders.ToArray())
    CognitoAwsCredentials.RemoveLogin(provider);
CognitoAwsCredentials.Clear();  // get a new identity id
```

Explicitly calling CognitoAwsCredentials.GetCredentialsAsync() after sign-in results in the following exception:

```
Amazon.CognitoSync.SyncManager.Internal.Sqlite3Exception: Error executing statement Constraint
  at Amazon.CognitoSync.SyncManager.Internal.SQLiteLocalStorage.Execute (System.String query, System.Object[] parameters) [0x000b1] in <62c37bae57154a9db28b11672ef24676>:0 
  at Amazon.CognitoSync.SyncManager.Internal.SQLiteLocalStorage.ExecuteMultipleHelper (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] statements) [0x00036] in <62c37bae57154a9db28b11672ef24676>:0 
  at Amazon.CognitoSync.SyncManager.Internal.SQLiteLocalStorage.ChangeIdentityId (System.String oldIdentityId, System.String newIdentityId) [0x0031c] in <62c37bae57154a9db28b11672ef24676>:0 
  at Amazon.CognitoSync.SyncManager.CognitoSyncManager.IdentityChanged (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x0004f] in <62c37bae57154a9db28b11672ef24676>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.EventHandler`1[Amazon.CognitoIdentity.CognitoAWSCredentials+IdentityChangedArgs]:invoke_void_object_TEventArgs (object,Amazon.CognitoIdentity.CognitoAWSCredentials/IdentityChangedArgs)
  at Amazon.CognitoIdentity.CognitoAWSCredentials.UpdateIdentity (System.String newIdentityId) [0x0003d] in <582789cfd3e945e89e215d9a53e2bee6>:0 
  at Amazon.CognitoIdentity.CognitoAWSCredentials+<GetPoolCredentialsAsync>d__59.MoveNext () [0x001c3] in <582789cfd3e945e89e215d9a53e2bee6>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at Amazon.CognitoIdentity.CognitoAWSCredentials+<GenerateNewCredentialsAsync>d__57.MoveNext () [0x00126] in <582789cfd3e945e89e215d9a53e2bee6>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.RefreshingAWSCredentials+<GetCredentialsAsync>d__8.MoveNext () [0x00035] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Credentials\RefreshingAWSCredentials.cs:104
```

An Sqlite related exception is also thrown when trying to store a value by calling DataSet.Put(...) after the sign-in:

```
Amazon.CognitoSync.SyncManager.Internal.Sqlite3Exception: Error executing statement Error
  at Amazon.CognitoSync.SyncManager.Internal.SQLiteLocalStorage.Execute (System.String query, System.Object[] parameters) [0x000b1] in <62c37bae57154a9db28b11672ef24676>:0 
  at Amazon.CognitoSync.SyncManager.Internal.SQLiteLocalStorage.ExecuteMultipleHelper (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] statements) [0x00000] in <62c37bae57154a9db28b11672ef24676>:0 
  at Amazon.CognitoSync.SyncManager.Internal.SQLiteLocalStorage.PutValueHelper (System.String identityId, System.String datasetName, System.String key, System.String value) [0x00198] in <62c37bae57154a9db28b11672ef24676>:0 
  at Amazon.CognitoSync.SyncManager.Internal.SQLiteLocalStorage.PutValue (System.String identityId, System.String datasetName, System.String key, System.String value) [0x00010] in <62c37bae57154a9db28b11672ef24676>:0 
  at Amazon.CognitoSync.SyncManager.Dataset.Put (System.String key, System.String value) [0x00018] in <62c37bae57154a9db28b11672ef24676>:0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If the user is changing then the IdentityId is changed. On signout try clearing the SyncManager cache using WipeData() https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CognitoSync/MCognitoSyncManagerWipeData.html

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it out, but unfortunately it still crashes with the same exception. As mentioned above it crashes after sign-in. after sign-out everything seems to work as expected.